# Copy the 2 most recent files to a destination

Tags: powershell

I found this script in another thread.

```
$ChildFolders = @('A', 'B')

for($i = 0; $i -lt $ChildFolders.Count; $i++){
    $FolderPath = "D:\BackupSource\" + $ChildFolders[$i]
    $DestinationPath = "D:\BackupDestination\" + $ChildFolders[$i]

    gci -Path $FolderPath -File | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select FullName -First 1 | %($_) { 
        $_.FullName
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $DestinationPath 
    }
}
```

I need this piece of code to not only copy the first item, but also the second one to the destination.

So the 2 most recent files need to be copied from folder1 to folder2. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update:

```
Select FullName -First 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment for a sysadmin who tries to script a bit, now and then.

Comment: @Furr_xL - My apologies, that was indeed uncalled for. *Comment removed*